# Finding Cells in which all values of fixed array are present

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array with fixed values. How can I find cells in Column B that contain all the 'String' values present in array?

Here is my code

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    Dim kwrSets As Variant
    .Activate
    kwrSets = .Range("B2:B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(2, .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row)).Value
    For k = LBound(kwrSets) To UBound(kwrSets)
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Delete entire row if all values of arr not found in kwrSets
        Next i
    Next k
End With
```

Following is the updated code based on the answer below but it is giving error "Subscript out of range" in inStr line.

```
Sub Extractor()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsd As Worksheet
Dim cell As Variant
Dim tmp As Variant
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim j As Long, i As Long
Dim kwrSets() As Variant
Dim arr() As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    .Activate
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If (cell.Offset(0, 2) = 1) Then
            tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
        End If
    Next cell
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
    arr = Split(tmp, "|")
End With

Set wsd = Worksheets("Data")
With wsd
    .Activate
    kwrSets = .Range("B2:B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(2, .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row)).Value
    For k = LBound(kwrSets) To UBound(kwrSets)
        blnFound = True
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(kwrSets(j, 1), arr(i)) = 0 Then
                blnFound = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next k
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some VBA code that gets all of the data in column B into an array, then loops this array checking for the existence of each of the elements in the search array. If any of the search elements are not found, then it exits that loop. If all elements are found then it highlights the cell.

```
Sub sFindArray()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aSearch() As Variant
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngFirstRow As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLBound As Long
    Dim lngUBound As Long
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    aSearch = Array("a", "b", "c")
    lngLBound = LBound(aSearch)
    lngUBound = UBound(aSearch)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    aData() = ws.Range("B1:B" & lngLastRow)
    lngFirstRow = LBound(aData, 1)
    lngLastRow = UBound(aData, 1)
    For lngLoop1 = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
        blnFound = True
        For lngLoop2 = lngLBound To lngUBound
            If InStr(aData(lngLoop1, 1), aSearch(lngLoop2)) = 0 Then
                blnFound = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngLoop2
        If blnFound = True Then
            ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: I have used your code to construct my code but I am getting error at inStr line. Please check my original post with update.

Comment: Oh, I was using j instead of k. Now resolved. Thanks

Comment: That's why you should always use `Option Explicit` in your code - when you do a "Compile" it would have immediately highlighted this.